# How to remove features from farm?

Tags: visual-studio, error, deployment

I have figured out  a way to uninstall and remove the wsp from manage farm solutions. (Solution Management) - `http://centraladmin:8888/_admin/Solutions.aspx`

But I donotknow how to uninstall and delete the feature. Because, when deploying some projects via VS we get error as given below, how do I remove the these features causing problem:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Failed to load
>   receiver assembly "InternalMaster, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b11cf6a2b4fe2871" for feature
>   "InternalMaster_Activate Internal Master" (ID:
>   28083f8d-cdac-4869-86d7-594b7890536d).:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'InternalMaster, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b11cf6a2b4fe2871' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'InternalMaster,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b11cf6a2b4fe2871'
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Sometimes it gives error as feature is already present, set force to true.

If we set the feature property 'force' then it gives foll. error on deploying via VS:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Operation is
>   not valid due to the current state of the object.

Comment: How did you 'figure out a way to uninstall'? Try a IISRESET or reboot, that may clear things up.

Comment: Are you saying that you set  `AlwaysForceInstall = true` and you still get error

Comment: yes I get the last error.

Answer (score 1):

As is evident from the first error there is an issue with finding assembly information. This may mean you may have changed namespace, class name etc. Normally `AlwaysForceInstall = true` should take care of the feature which is not uninstalled. Value `TRUE` specifies that the Feature is installed by force during installation even if the Feature is already installed. 
Moreover, the second error reinforces that something has changed in the solution. Check the `Elements.xml` file where assembly information for the event receiver is available. Check that your namespace, class name are correct.
See this for more info: http://suehernandez.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object/

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://spfeatureadministration.codeplex.com/) free tool from community!
Using this tool you can remove faulty features.
I hope that the error will disappear.
May be solve your trouble!

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Great! Looking forward to it!